# Knockout unable to process binding With, options, etc

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have a Single page app with side bar / side menu

```js
function MyApp() {
  this.Menus = ko.observableArray();
  this.paginatedRecordList = ko.observableArray();

  this.Menus.push({
    Selected: true,
    IconClass: 'fa-dashboard',
    Title: "Dashboard",
    Route: "#dashboard",
    MenuItems: []
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    IconClass: 'fa-laptop',
    Title: "Item Management",
    Route: null,
    MenuItems: [{
        Title: 'Product',
        IconClass: 'fa-shopping-cart',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#product'
      },
      {
        Title: 'Product Category',
        IconClass: 'fa-list-ol',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#product-category'
      },
      {
        Title: 'Product Subcategory',
        IconClass: 'fa-list-ul',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#product-subcategory'
      }
    ]
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    IconClass: 'fa-truck',
    Title: "Supplier",
    Route: "#supplier",
    MenuItems: []
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    IconClass: 'fa-users',
    Title: "Customer",
    Route: "#customer",
    MenuItems: []
  }, {
    Selected: false,
    IconClass: 'fa-database',
    Title: "Inventory",
    Route: null,
    MenuItems: [{
        Title: 'Stock In',
        IconClass: 'fa-download',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#stock-in'
      },
      {
        Title: 'Stock Adjustment',
        IconClass: 'fa-upload',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#stock-adjustment'
      },
      {
        Title: 'Delivery Receipt',
        IconClass: 'fa-clipboard',
        Selected: ko.observable(false),
        Route: '#delivery-receipt'
      }
    ]
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyApp());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: paginatedRecordList">
    <tr role="row">
      <td class="visible-lg">
        <p data-bind="text: Code"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="visible-lg">
        <p data-bind="text: PaymentTermIdName"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p data-bind="text: MobilePhone"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="visible-md visible-lg">
        <p data-bind="text: MainPhone"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
        <p data-bind="text: ContactPerson"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-md-2 visible-lg">
        <p data-bind="text: moment(ModifiedOn).format('DD-MMM-YYYY h:mm A')"></p>
      </td>
      <td class="col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
        <div class="row pull-right">
          <a href="#" title="edit record" class="click-edit" data-bind="click: ClickEdit">
            <p class="fa fa-edit col-sm-3"></p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" title="delete record" class="click-delete" data-bind="click: ClickDelete">
            <p class="fa fa-trash-o col-sm-3"></p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

the error says

```
ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function(){return paginatedRecordList }"
Message: Unable to process binding "text: function(){return Code }"
Message: Code is not defined
```

every time I navigate to Stock In and then click visit another menu some error occurs `ReferenceError: Uable to process binding .....`

hope someone can help me, if you need more information please ask.

Comment: You have a `foreach: paginatedRecordList` binding, and if it says "`Code` is not defined" then that's what's going on. One of the items in the paginated records list does not have a `Code` property. It's best if you make a sample that reproduces the error. Include the input data.

Comment: I've updated your code sample to a stub of a reproduction. Please add the missing bits yourself so that the error you see is triggered.

Comment: Yes, It Says that `Code is not Defined` but like I said , it only happen after I visited Stock In module, the rest of the module don't have error. like when I click  `Dashboard` and click back to Supplier, The Error `"Code" is not defined` didn't trigger , I tried commenting `Stock In` menu and test if the error will trigger in other modules, but its not.

Comment: And like I said, modify the code sample I started for you so that the error is triggered. There is no way of *guessing* what might be wrong. You need to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2):

I´d say the error is very self-explaining.

```
Message: Code is not defined
```

just reflects that there is no property Code defined in your example data entries

```
{
    Selected: false,
    IconClass: 'fa-truck',
    Title: "Supplier",
    Route: "#supplier",
    MenuItems: []
 }
```

So the question arises why you even expect a property code when you never supplied it.

If you expect some results to have a code and on some it´s undefined I´m always using ternary operator

```
data-bind="text: Code ? Code : 'No Code' "
```

Comment: You could save some repetition and use the OR operator for that: `data-bind="text: Code || 'No Code'"`